# How 32-bit application can run on 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, wow64

In Richter's "CLR via CSharp" book there is a following table explaining how application built in different ways will run on various versions on Windows. It says that application built with **x86** platform switch will run on 64-bit OS as a WoW64 application which is perfectly fine, but it also tells that with **anycpu32bitpreferred** switch it will run *as a 32-bit application*. So the question is how 32-bit application can run on 64-bit OS other than as a WoW64?

[image]

Comment: I believe it is a typo in the table (the "Runs as a 32-bit application" at the intersection of anycpu32bitpreferred and x64 should read "Runs as a WoW64 application"). Then again, it can be the other way round too (the "Runs as a WoW64 application" could be "Runs as a 32-bit application", because *the* way to run a 32-bit application on x64 is WoW64, thus saying "as 32-bit" already implies the use of WoW).

Comment: The table is outdated, Windows RT is dead and a column for 64-bit ARM platforms is missing.  A 32-bit app always needs the wow64 emulator, on ARM as well.  Otherwise the reason that the "Prefer 32-bit" option got added, targeting x86 doesn't make much sense on an ARM device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typo. It's mentioned in the errata for the book:

> Page 10, Table 1-2, second row, x64 Windows column
>
> Reads: Runs as a 32-bit application
>
> Should read: Runs as a WoW64 application
>
> Date corrected: 3/8/2013